# Problem with Google Hybrid Protocol (OpenID + OAuth) Demo

Tags: openid, oauth

I'm trying to use the googlesample for the [hybrid protocol(OpenID+OAuth)](http://googlecodesamples.com/hybrid/), but for some reason it is not working for me

```
You are not authenticated
```

I tried to use the google account button, nothing happens!!
I tried entering my google openID and again nothing happens!!

Could this be a problem with the browser?? not likely!

Can you please report it if you get the same results or if someone have a clue about whats going on, please share, thanx

Answer (score 1):

I gave it another try and it worked this time. The problem was that I was signed in with 2 different Google accounts at the same time and for some reason I didn't get a redirect to Google Account's sign-in manager page.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked Yahoo openID + OAuth implementation and get this Warning message

```
 WARNING - PLEASE READ

Yahoo is strongly encouraging Yahoo! end-users not to authorize any new applications using OAuth until the recently discovered security issue with the OAuth protocol is resolved. Yahoo! is not aware of any exploits of this issue prior to April 23, 2009.

If you click the "continue at your own risk" button below, your private data may be exposed to unintended third parties.

Note: Unless you click "Continue at your own risk," your data has not been shared.

Note to Developers: Developers who are authorizing their own apps, for the purposes of testing, may proceed at their own risk. Yahoo! recommends that developers create test accounts with test data for testing their application.
```

Apparently, something fishy is going on with OAuth, however I can't see if Google made any announcements with this regard nor Plaxo!

Comment: The recent OAuth security hole does not affect the OpenID+OAuth extension.  That doesn't mean Google hasn't disabled it though.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and it works for me.

This [OpenID+OAuth demo](http://samples.dotnetopenauth.net/master/OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms/loginPlusOAuth.aspx) also worked against Google just now ([Source code](https://github.com/AArnott/dotnetopenid/blob/master/samples/OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms/loginPlusOAuth.aspx.cs)).